# Opening files without knowing the name

Tags: c++, fstream

I want to run a loop, which will open all the files in folder and perform some operations on them. However, when I try to pass

```
"*.*"
```

in
    stream.open()

, it doesn't open any file. ( `is_good()` returns `false` )

```
fstream stream;
stream.open("*.*", fstream::out);
```

Comment: what would you expect it to do? how could you handle the files at once?

Comment: It could open first file it finds, but now I see the flaw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use something like `dirent.h` or boost's FileSystem Api to find out all the files in the directory `*.*` and store them in an `std::vector` or something. And then loop over the vector and open all of the files.

```
for(int i = 0; i < files.size(); i++)
{
   stream.open(files[i], fstream::out);
}
```